# What property is needed for combo boxes?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-c++, combobox

Basically I have created an app that reads and writes values in text boxes to an XML file. Instead of using all text boxes I want to add in some combo boxes but I am not sure what property is needed for it.

```
 String ^strMake  = this->txtMake->Text;
             String ^strModel = this->txtModel->Text;
             String ^strName = this->txtName->Text;
             String ^strParentPart = this->txtParentPart->Text;
             String ^strPartID = this->txtPartId->Text;
             String ^strPartType = this->comboBox1->???????????????
```

(The question marks is what I need to fill in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not clear, there are some properties you might be interested in: Text, SelectedText, SelectedItem, SelectedValue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C++ programmer, but can you try `SelectedText` property?